# Visual Studio Code 1.14 - Breakpoint set but not yet bound

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, breakpoints, vscode-debugger

My debugger isnt working when I launch it. I have seen several posts with solutions like "solutions explorer" which I cant seem to find in my VS Code or change from "Release" to "Debug" which also I dont seem to have or im blind...

This is what I have in my **launch.json**

```
    // Use IntelliSense para saber los atributos posibles.
    // Mantenga el puntero para ver las descripciones de los existentes atributos
    // Para más información, visite: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8100/#/Home/dashboardApp",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--args",
                "--disable-web-security",
                "--allow-file-access-from-files",
                "--allow-running-insecure-content",
                "--ignore-certificate-errors",
            ],
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is the information about my **Visual Studio Code**:

- Versión: 1.41.1
- Commit: 26076a4de974ead31f97692a0d32f90d735645c0
- Fecha: 2019-12-18T14:57:51.166Z
- Electron: 6.1.5
- Chrome: 76.0.3809.146
- Node.js: 12.4.0
- V8: 7.6.303.31-electron.0
- OS: Darwin x64 18.6.0

Answer (score 1):

In my case to debug Vue app, I specified the following values in launch.json file.

```
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/<vue-app-folder>/src",
        "breakOnLoad": true,
        "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
            "webpack:///./src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
            "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*"
        }
```

You need replace the <vue-app-folder> with your folder name.

Answer (score 0):

Run Ionic serve and check what url it opens e.g. http://localhost:8100/smsalerts

then change url in configurations to be the same, as below

```
"configurations": [
  {
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
    "url": "http://localhost:8100/smsalerts",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
```